# What is the difference between LFCS and LPIC?

Tags: career

I'm a little confused as to which certification I should go for: LPIC or LFCS.

What are the differences between them? How can I decide which one to choose?

Comment: I would go for a RHCE rather than either of these.  The RHCE is the premier Linux certification.

Comment: @fpmurphy1 but isn't RHCE certification specific for redhat distribution while LPIC does cover more than one? so what are the pros of RHCE and why go for it?

Comment: The reality is that Red Hat is the commercial leader in Linux distributions

Answer (score 2):

LPIC is multi-choice or a fill in the blank kind of exam. They test more on commands and topics.

LFCS is a more handson exam. Their questions are more of like provide permissions to files, transfer files via SFTP or SCP etc. They are like handson exercises.

So if you are aiming for a system admin role, I would say you can give LFCS.

Since LFCS is a sys admin level exam, RHCE is irrelevant here. You can give RHCSA too if you are seriously considering getting a real job at a big enterprise.